# Write actual values to bar chart using Gruff within Ruby

Tags: ruby, charts, gruff

I am generating a bar chart with values `[1,5,10,23]`. Currently, I have no way of knowing those exact values when looking at the image generated by Gruff. I just know that `23` falls somewhere between the lines of `20` and `25`.

Is it possible to write the exact values within the image?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for labels

```
g = Gruff::Bar.new
g.title = 'Wow!  Look at this!'
g.data = "something", [1,5,10,23]
g.labels = { 0 => '1', 1 => '5', 2 => '10', 3 => '23'}
```

Read the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/topfunky/gruff/frames) for more info on labels

Comment: I was hoping there was something I could use to write the "labels" above the bars, within the image. Not necessarily as a label on the bottom of the graph. I do think I can make this work though if there is no other option, so thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
g.show_labels_for_bar_values = true
```